# UINavigation Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to navigate a class on a button click option in a View Controller class. Please give the way to do this. I am using the given following code to do this on a button click.

```
- (void)buttonAction {
  Status *status = [[Status alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:status animated:YES];
}

// Status is a UIViewController subclass
```

Comment: Your application is navigation based or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(void)buttonAction
{
  Status *status = [[Status alloc]init];//this is not proper
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:status animated:YES]; 
}
```

you must use

```
(void)buttonAction
{
  Status *status = [[Status alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourNib" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:status animated:YES]; 
  [status release];
}
```

here your nib is the name of xib which you want to display.

Edit:

now you application is view based so

(void)buttonAction
    {
      so make object of appDelegate class(suppos objApp)
      now,

```
  Status *status = [[Status alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourNib" bundle:nil];
  [objApp.window addSubview:status.view]; 
  [status release];
}
```

Comment: Your code still leaks the Status object. You should add `[status release];` at the end and fix code formatting.

Comment: ok now i am using this but still it's not working :(        Status *status = [[Status alloc]initWithNibName:@"Status" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:status animated:YES];
 [status release];

Comment: check your xib it having controller file as status or not.

Comment: also tell me one thing your application is navigation based or not.

Comment: Ishu, highlight the block of code and hit the button with the 1s and 0s, next to the big quotation mark. This will indent your code block, and format it nicely.

Comment: I believe that nib-loading is one of those magical things where `[[YourSubclass alloc] init]` will automatically search for a nib with the same name as the class, and then redirect to `-initWithNibName:bundle:`. But I could be wrong about that.

Comment: @jonathan, I think you are right,main thing is just set xib controller class.

Comment: give the detail how can i get this. And FYI, this nib file created when i was creating the particular class file.

Comment: And I am Using the View Based Application.

Comment: ok thats why you face problem (view based application).so see edit answer

Comment: Heee,Is there any way to resolve it. because i already take a View based application and i want to push the view instead of add view.

Comment: @Ishu, Thanks for giving me detail and i am creating new application with navigation based application,it's working... :)

Comment: @sandy you need to accepy an answer and vote it up if it works for you.by sily check the check mark and click on up arrow before answer.If you want next time help for any one.it really matters.

Comment: @Ishu I try but it shows "Vote Up requires 15 reputation". So w8 i do for this :(

Comment: @Ishu, he now, I get it na... :)

Comment: Ok thank you it also increase your repotation and repo shows how community can trust you.

Comment: now your repo is 15 so you can vote now. thanx in advance buddy.

Comment: @Ishu, Again Thanks allot Dear.. :). but can you tell me how can i join any chat room.

Comment: Brother you need more repo for that read faq.Thanx now any one can answers your question.