# iphone UIViewController base subclass not showing view in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I had the idea to subclass UIViewController as a base class for my subsequent controllers with the purpose of adding a "logout" button to the UINavigationController in my app delegate.

```
//MyAppDelegate.m
@synthesize navigationController; //UINavigationController

//-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions...
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
...
```

In my MainWindow.xib I have a NavigationController attached to.. navigationController with **DashboardViewController** as its root view controller.

```
//BaseLogoutViewController.m

- (void)loadView {
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Logout", @"")
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(logoutPressed)];

   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
   [addButton release];
   [super loadView];
}

// -(void)logoutPressed callback implemented
// viewDidLoad, didRecieveMemoryWarning, dealloc implemented

//DashboardViewController.h
@interface DashboardViewController : BaseLogoutViewController { }
```

[image: DashboardViewController : UIViewController]
**DashboardViewController : UIViewController**

[image: DashboardViewController : BaseLogoutViewController]
**DashboardViewController : BaseLogoutViewController**

The good news is it does show the logout button, but the dashboard does not show it's own view.
**BaseLogoutViewController** does not have a Nib of its own.
My question is, how come when I subclass BaseLogoutViewController it no longer shows my **DashboardViewController's** view?

Comment: try this and i hope u will get the solution for your problem. Please read all the comments given below for this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436278/uinavigation-problem

Comment: I appear to be doing what that answer says. The only difference is I am adding the navigationController's subview which adds Dashboard's view because it is specified in the Nib. the problem occurs when I derive the dashboard from my custom UIViewController class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

things you have implied, but i'd like to confirm:

- you are going to have more than one view controller pushed/popped onto the navigation controller?
- you want the logout button on every view that gets pushed onto the navigation controller?

that said, `loadView` is **not** what you want to override, `viewDidLoad` is where you want to put the above code,

'loadView` is responsible for (oddly enough) loading the view, which it is not doing, by overriding it, you have prevented it from happening, you want to augment the view once it has been loaded,

Comment: wow that worked. This is strange, because I had tried viewDidLoad instead before and it didnt work, perhaps i did not call [super viewDidLoad]. I also find it strange that loadView did not work despite you saying it shouldn't. I think it might be because I did not have a loadView in my dashboard class with a [super loadView]; anyways, thank you very much.

Comment: yes, placing a `[super loadView]` in the first try should work, but preferred implementation is in `viewDidLoad` for some esoteric reasons (other than it's the preferred design) that i have not stored in my cranial area.

Comment: aside: `loadView` can either be responsible for loading from a nib (which is likely what the superclass is doing), or for programmatically creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [super loadView] in your  - (void)loadView method...that'll do the trick.

Comment: according to the documentation you should not call `[super loadView]`